# docker-compose scale - agent instance id

Tags: docker, containers, docker-compose

When I use `docker-compose scale` I would like to have an instance id used in the yml file.

docker-compose.yml:

```
myservice:
  volumes:
  - ./volumes/foo{AGENT_ID}/bar:/foo/bar
```

I have seen a lot of discussions around this topic but I still have not found a clear answer.

Is there an environment variable or similar that I can use this way? It would be ideal if I could use that in bash scripts, etc.

Comment: Currently I doubt there is a way, I am working on article which shows an alternate possible way to do this. Will post as soon as it is ready

Comment: Hi Tarun, thanks. I posted another similar question. I am definitely looking forward to that article but unfortunately I need an answer sooner :) Maybe someone has some idea..

Comment: Hopefully max by tomorrow

Comment: That would be amazing!! Please send the link once you post it! Looking forward to it

Comment: Hi Tarun, did you manage to publish your article?

Comment: I got part-1 of the approach working, just publishing that one in few hours. part-2 needs more effort

Comment: This is a unedited draft, shared because you are in a hurry http://tarunlalwani.com/post/docker-compose-scale-with-dynamic-configuration-part-1/

Comment: Do let me know your feedback so I can finalize the article and improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am aware that this might not be a perfect solution but if you don't mind sharing data between nodes.. it does work well. I am using this for local tests so it is safe in my case.

Docker-compose.yml

```
...
volumes:
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
...
```

Dockerfile

```
...
RUN pip3 install docker
...
```

In each node, I deploy the following script `get_name.py`

```
from docker import Client
import os

hostname = os.environ['HOSTNAME']

cli = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
data = cli.containers()

for d in data:
    id = d['Id'][:12]
    names = d['Names']
    if id == hostname:
        print(names[0])
        quit()

print(hostname)
```

And when the node starts (`start.sh`), it queries its name and creates a symlink to the corresponding subdirectory:

```
...
NODE_NAME=$(python /root/scripts/get_name.py)
OWN_VOLUME_NAME="/shared_volumes${NODE_NAME}"
ln -s ${OWN_VOLUME_NAME} /data
...
```